# What terminologies and concepts describe the codes that follow a format of Text1.Text2()?

Tags: serial

I'm just really curious because some codes really follow a format like this. Examples include serial.begin(), serial.println() and when I used servomotors the left part was the name of the servomotor, which I declared. I want to know what concept does the code with a format of Text1.Text2() refer to? What do you call Text1 and Text2? Are there official or commonly used terminologies for the concepts and parts such as "variable", "statement", "code"?

To add to my understanding, it appears that Text1 refers to an object and that Text2 has the concept of "function" where it performs something related to the object. Though I would think that another terminology would be possessed by Text2 other than function to distinguish it from a function since it is required to be written in the format I mentioned, which next to the object with a period separating them and no spaces at all.

Comment: the names differ amongst different programming  languages ... your question has nothing to do with the Arduino, so it is off topic here .... look at details about a programming language of interest ... see what the names are

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_classes.asp

Comment: @jsotola: It's not mainly the _names_ that differ, but their semantic meaning. What `Text1.Text2()` could mean differs greatly by language, even if this may be a syntactically valid statement in many languages.

Comment: Text1 is an instance of some class xxx; xxx::Text2() is it's method function.

Comment: As @KIIV wrote, the overall concept is the class concept. A class is the build description of an object with its own member functions and member variables. From a class you can declare instances as variables in your code. Thats, what `Text1` is here: An instance of a class. `Text2()` in turn is a member function of that class, which can act upon the variables of that particular instance. You can google tutorials about C++ classes to find out more. Note, that in C/C++ classes and structs are very similar. So you use a similar syntax to refer to member variables of a struct instance.

Comment: Class and method are probably the answers I need. Thanks! It's just so hard to search with Google if you don't have the correct keywords to obtain what idea you want clarified.

Comment: 'Text1' is usually an object. Object is an instance of a class. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Objects_and_classesg

Answer (score 1):

The over-arching concept is *Object Oriented Programming* ([OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)).

The terms I was taught at University - taking `Serial.println()` as an example:

- `Serial` is an *instance* of a *class* (in this case `HardwareSerial`), sometimes called an *object*.
- `println()` (a function in a class) is a *method* of a class.
- A "variable" in a class is called a *property* of a class.

A commented code example:

```cpp
class Foo { // This is the *class*

    public: // These symbols are accessible from outside the class

        int bar; // This is a public property

        void baz() { ​// This is a public method
        }

    private: // These symbols are only available from inside the class

       ​int meep; // This is a private property

       ​void moop() { // this is a private method
       }
};


Foo bar; // Instantiate an instance of the Foo class and call it bar.
```